# How to tell if text on the windows clipboard is ISO 8859 or UTF-8 in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, clipboard

I would like to know if there is an easy way to detect if the text on the clipboard is in ISO 8859 or UTF-8 ?

Here is my current code:

```
    COleDataObject  obj;

    if (obj.AttachClipboard())
    {
        if (obj.IsDataAvailable(CF_TEXT))
        {
            HGLOBAL hmem = obj.GetGlobalData(CF_TEXT);
            CMemFile sf((BYTE*) ::GlobalLock(hmem),(UINT) ::GlobalSize(hmem));
            CString buffer;

            LPSTR str = buffer.GetBufferSetLength((int)::GlobalSize(hmem));
            sf.Read(str,(UINT) ::GlobalSize(hmem));
            ::GlobalUnlock(hmem);

            //this is my string class
            s->SetEncoding(ENCODING_8BIT);
            s->SetString(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ISO 8859-what? There's 8859-1, 8859-2, etc.

Comment: Part of the problem is that appears unknown as well. You'd need CF_LOCALE to tell. Once you have that, the entire question is pretty much answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the definition of CF_LOCALE at [this Microsoft page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649013(VS.85).aspx).  It tells you the locale of the text in the clipboard.  Better yet, if you use CF_UNICODETEXT instead, Windows will convert to UTF-16 for you.

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 has a defined structure for non-ASCII bytes. You can scan for bytes >= 128, and if any are detected, check if they form a valid UTF-8 string.

The valid UTF-8 byte formats can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

```
Unicode             Byte1           Byte2           Byte3           Byte4
U+000000-U+00007F   0xxxxxxx
U+000080-U+0007FF   110xxxxx        10xxxxxx
U+000800-U+00FFFF   1110xxxx        10xxxxxx        10xxxxxx
U+010000-U+10FFFF   11110xxx        10xxxxxx        10xxxxxx        10xxxxxx
```

---

old answer:

You don't have to -- all ASCII text is valid UTF-8, so you can just decode it as UTF-8 and it will work as expected.

To test if it contains non-ASCII characters, you can scan for bytes >= 128.

Comment: I guess I didn't really mean 7 bit ascii, CF_TEXT returns chars from 0 - 255, so it is more like ISO/IEC 8859. I had a problem with this as french accents with values typically between 130 and 162 only take 1 byte in 8859 but they need 2 bytes to be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: ASCII is by definition 7-bit. I'll edit your question to be a bit more clear.

Comment: If you find the two characters C0 A0. What do you have? It is valid 'code point' in UTF-8 but it is also two valid characters in ISO 8859. This is not a reliable method.

Comment: @Martin: There is no reliable method for this, guessing is the best that can be achieved.

Comment: @John: Guessing is the best method if you ONLY have text. You can ask the clipboard object for what it thinks.

Answer (score 1):

I can be mistaken, but I think you cannot: if I open an UTF-8 file without Bom in my editor, it is displayed by default as ISO-8859-1 (my locale), and beside some strange use of foreign (for me) accented chars, I have no strong visual hint that it is UTF-8 (unless it is encoded in another way elsewhere, eg. charset declaration in HTML or XML): it is perfectly valid Ansi text.

John wrote "all ASCII text is valid UTF-8" but the reverse is true.

Windows XP+ uses naturally UTF-16, and have a clipboard format for it, but AFAIK it just ignore UTF-8, with no special treatment for it.
(Well, there is an API to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 (or Ansi, etc.), actually).

Comment: File is different from clipboard. File can have different encoding depending on the byte length of each character inside. I wrote a method to detect character encoding this way after BOM detection failed. In contrast, there's no way to detect clipboard encoding from byte length so it's provided as Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see obj.IsDataAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) to see if a unicode version of what's on the clipboard is available.

-Adam

Comment: I actually had code to detect this but I had weird problems with it sometimes I would get gibberish results. I think I know what the problem was now though. I assumed that the string pointed to a UTF-8 string but it think it can point to many formats and I need to call WideCharToMultiByte on it.

Comment: Yeah, a common problem with unicode is it has many representations, only one of which is UTF8.